# Trying to gzip qcow2 files to a /backup directory

Tags: shell-script, backup, gzip

I have some files in a directory; some of them are .qcow2 extensions. I want to backup only the files having .qcow2 extension.

Example: I have 5 files with .qc0w2 exxtension, they are: vm1.qcow2, vm2.qcow2,vm3.qcow2, vm4.qcow2 and minnow.qcow2. My intention is to use the gzip command to back them up into the /backup directory. It should be like the following: vm1.qcow2.backup.gz, vm2.qcow2.backup.gz, vm3.qcow2.backup.gz, vm4.qcow2.backup.gz and minnow.qcow2.backup.gz

I tried the following command:

```
   gzip < *.qcow2 > /backup/*.qcow2.backup.gz
```

but this is not working. Can you please help me what mistakes I have done?

Comment: At least show the error & result, versus what you expected.

Comment: Example: I have 5 files with .qc0w2 exxtension, they are: vm1.qcow2, vm2.qcow2,vm3.qcow2, vm4.qcow2 and minnow.qcow2. Now My intention is to use gzip command to back them up in /backup directory. it should be like the following:
vm1.qcow2.backup.gz, vm2.qcow2.backup.gz, vm3.qcow2.backup.gz, vm4.qcow2.backup.gz and minnow.qcow2.backup.gz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want a combined archive, loop over each file and compress it to its own backup file:

```
for file in *.qcow2
do
  gzip -c "$file" > /backup/"$file".backup.gz
done
```

The `-c` option says to send the compressed results to stdout, which we redirect to the filename we'd prefer.

Comment: thanks a lot. before that do i need to do this command???
      
        $file = ls | grep *.qcow2

Comment: Absolutely not. The `file` variable gets assigned as part of the `for` loop and the `*.qcow2` glob.

Comment: but what if I want to mention the location. I mean from which directory it will search for the .qcow2 files.

Comment: The current directory, just like your example in the question.

Comment: but if i want to mention the location specific???

Comment: Simplest would be to just `cd` there first. Otherwise you’d need to strip the directory portion off before using the name for the /backup directory.

Answer (score 3):

gzip by itself doesn't have an option to output the zip files to another directory, you would have to do that in another command.

```
gzip *.qcow2 -S .backup.gz
mv *.qcow2.backup.gz /backup
```

Comment: [`gzip` on some BSD systems](https://man.openbsd.org/gzip) have a `-o` option for specifying the output filename.